# Group operation and transitive actions

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a finite set on which group $G$ operates transitively, and let $U$ be a subset of $S$. Prove that every element of $S$ is in the same number of sets $gU$.

My attempt: I know that there is one orbit of $S$. Also, since $G$ operates transitively, it is the same as $G$ operates on $G/H$. But I don't know where to go on from here.Any hwlp will be appreciated

Comment: If $s \in gU$, then $g^{-1} s = \in U$. Formulated this way, the question is asking you to show that each element of $s$ is sent in $U$ by $G$ the same number of times. So, let $s_1$, $s_2$ be elements of $S$, and $s_1 = h s_2$ ($h \in G$) by transitivity...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are elements of $S$. We want to exhibit a bijection

$$\{gU\ni a\}\xrightarrow{\sim}\{gU\ni b\}.$$

(The first is the set of $gU$s containing $a$, the second the set of $gU$s containing $b$.)

By transitivity we have $b=ha$ for some $h\in G$. And $a\in gU\Leftrightarrow ha\in hgU$. So what might you conjecture this bijective map to be, explicitly?

Comment: the map needed could be $gU\rightarrow xgU$ where $x\in G$

Comment: @user104221 What is $x$?

Comment: $x$ is an arbitrary element of $G$

Comment: While the map will be *of the form* $gU\to xgU$ for some $x$, you cannot just choose an arbitrary element of $G$ for $x$. Please think about the information I've given in my answer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what the question actually wants us to do? I dont have the clear idea of what the question is asking. Thus, I don't know why we need a bijection in the first place?

Comment: @user104221 The question is asking you to prove the number of translates $gU$ ($g\in G$) of the subset $U\subseteq G$ which contain a given element $a$ is independent of the choice of $a$.

Comment: The $x$ will be the one which will be carrying $a$ to $b$

Comment: Correct. ${}{}$